# Twitter Bootstrap when mobile smaller margin for container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Yesterday I started my first bootstrap dev day. As a designer this looks like one super framework to work with but I have one problem:

As a app designer I know how important readability is on mobile devices. The bootstrap framework autosize the container but on mobile devices I would like to apply less margin from the edges so text will have larger lines (and less scrolling).

How do I apply this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

From the source code.
bootstrap-responsive@line 803

`body {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}`

Modify the value to get more space.